# Insert ROM in PDA file

Tags: custom-roms, rom, device-firmware, rom-update

I have a problem. I am new in the domain of android customization and that is why I am testing.

I have a PDA file for my old GT-S6102 Galaxy Y, which contains the following files:

- boot.img
- param.lfs
- Sbl.bin
- system.img
- userdata.img

I also downloaded a custom ROM from the internet called evo_x2.1 (evo_x2.1.zip) which contains the following files:

- META-INF (folder)
- system (folder)
- installbusybox (file)

Normaly this file is supposed to be put on /sdcard and update the system partition only from recovery mode.

But I have a question: Can I edit my PDA file mentioned above by inserting this ROM in it? (so that when I flash this firmware with odin into my phone I will no longer have to update it with this ROM separately afterwards, manually)

I tried to create a system.img which contained the files included in the ROM file and replaced the system.img in the PDA file with the system.img I just created from the ROM file.But when I try to flash the PDA with Odin, it crashes while analyzing the file.

NOTE: there is no md5 hashsum at the end of the PDA so there is no problem concerning the integrity of the file.

Thank you, and any observations are welcomed.

Comment: IIRC the `.img` has to be EXT4... I never even thought of doing it this way so I don't have further info.